# Tornar o post-it (elemento) editável

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de deixar o *post-it* editável, de modo que quando ele for clicado já possa ser editado normalmente.

[image]

Abaixo está o meu código:

```js
$(".adicionar").click(function() {
   $('<div class="post-it">' +
        '<ul>'
          +'<li>'
            +'<a href="#">'
             +' <h2>Titulo</h2>'
                +'<p>Text Qualquer #1</p>'
            +'</a>'
         +' </li>'
        +'</ul>'
      +'</div>').insertAfter(this);
});
```

Comment: @LipESprY-defolga-, veja o [histórico de edição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/359269/revisions). Aparentemente, o que ele gostaria é deixar o elemento editável. Isso é notável pelo próprio título original da pergunta "_Torna o post It Editavel_ [...]"

Comment: @LuizFelipe antes de uma suposta resposta, cabe várias interpretações da pergunta - como já vimos. Não acha que é mais útil sinalizar e/ou comentar sugerindo uma edição por parte do autor pedindo que esclareça melhor?

Comment: Realmente, o comentário seria mais útil nesse contexto. No entanto, não penso que _omiti_ nenhuma informação relevante da pergunta, já que a intenção da edição foi corrigir os eventuais erros de ortografia que estavam presentes. Peço novamente, inclusive, que [reveja o histórico de edição da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/359269/revisions). De todo modo, peço perdão pela eventual _confusão_.

Comment: Vc quer so que ele seja editável ou ele vai ser um "form" que vc depois vai querer enviar o que estiver escrito para o banco ou algo assim?

Comment: exatamente isso, ao clickar ele virar um form ai edita ele normalmente, exemplo no dashboard do wordpress quando queremos editar a pagina do template, nos apertamo exemplo no titulo e escreve que sera salvo; entretanto o carinha aqui abaixo me salvou, pq agora so faço enviar, os dados editavel pra o banco de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa nem de Javascript para isto, dá para fazer somente com o atributo `contenteditable` do **HTML5**:

```css
.post-it {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffcb;
  padding: 15px;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
h1, p {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-it">
  <h1 contenteditable="true">Título Editável</h1>
  <p contenteditable="true">Textos quaisquer editáveis</p>
</div>
```

Comment: justamente isso fera, obrigado

Comment: Jóia mano, sucesso aí!